# Laravel 4 Form::selectMonth prepend month

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How can I prepend an option into laravel

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
```

**Result**

```
<select name="month">
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

**I want to prepend an option value=0 like this**

```
<select class="form-control" name="month">
    <option value="0">Month</option>
    <option value="1">January</option>
    <option value="2">February</option>
    <option value="3">March</option>
    <option value="4">April</option>
    <option value="5">May</option>
    <option value="6">June</option>
    <option value="7">July</option>
    <option value="8">August</option>
    <option value="9">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

And set the default or selected to the Month placeholder.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, so you'll have to create your own array:

```
$months = array(0 => 'Month');

foreach (range(1, 12) as $month)
{
    $months[$month] = strftime($format, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));
}
```

pass it to your views:

```
return View::make('viewname')->with('months', $months);
```

and use `Form::select()`:

```
 {{ Form::select('month', $months) }}
```

As a form macro it could be:

```
Form::macro('selectMonthWithDefault', function($name, $options = array(), $format = '%B')
{
    $months = array(0 => 'Month');

    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month)
    {
        $months[$month] = strftime($format, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));
    }

    return Form::select($name, $months);
});
```

And don't forget you can also extend the FormBuilder class and create a new `Form::selectMonth()`.

Comment: Im planning to create a Form::macro like this

Comment: Form::macro('selectMonths', function($name, $options)
{
   //
});

Answer (score 1):

create new file inside app/macros.php and copy paster this line of codes

```
Form::macro('selectMonths', function($name, $options = array(), $format = '%B')
{
    $months = array(0 => 'Month');

    foreach (range(1, 12) as $month)
    {
        $months[$month] = strftime($format, mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, 1));
    }

    return Form::select($name, $months, null, $options);
});
```

require macros.php in app/start/global.php