# Laravel Creating A Custom Form Macro Select Year and Month

Tags: php, html, laravel, macros, laravel-4

I need help building my laravel custom macro. In my *start/global.php* I required a *macros.php*

```
...
require app_path().'/macros.php';
```

and on my *macros.php* I have this code that I read in this [site](http://laravel.io/forum/06-03-2014-missing-0-index-for-selectmonth-and-selectyear-form-helpers).

```
Form::macro('selectMonths', function()
{
  $selectMonth = preg_replace('/></', '><option value="">Month</option><', Form::selectMonth('month'));

  return $selectMonth;
});
```

and the result is this.

```
<select class="form-control" name="month">
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="1">January</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="2">February</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="3">March</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="4">April</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="5">May</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="6">June</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="7">July</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="8">August</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="9">September</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="11">November</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
  <option value="12">December</option>
  <option value="">Month</option>
</select>
```

how can I add this Month before January and not after every month?

Thanks!

Comment: Discussion about this exactly with a different solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836731/laravel-4-formselectmonth-prepend-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Form::macro('selectMonths', function($name, $selected = null, $options = array())
{
    $selectMonth = preg_replace('/></', '><option value="">Month</option><', Form::selectMonth($name, $selected, $options), 1);

    return $selectMonth;
});

Form::macro('selectYears', function($name, $begin, $end, $selected = null, $options = array())
{
    $selectYear = preg_replace('/></', '><option value="">Year</option><', Form::selectYear($name, $begin, $end, $selected, $options), 1);

    return $selectYear;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this pattern:

```
/name="month">/
```

Code:

```
$selectMonth = preg_replace('/name="month">/', 'name="month"><option value="">Month</option>', Form::selectMonth('month'));
```

This should insert it only at the very top of your list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to get a list of years? If so, you don't need a custom Macro. Laravel has you covered:

```
{{ Form::selectYear('year', 2013, 2015) }}
```

And for the month:

```
{{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
```

Comment: Nope I need the year and the month with a placeholder like Select Month or Select Year or Just Year or Month and its value=""