# Laravel - Select - set Default option

Tags: php, forms, date, laravel

I'm having a small issue with my select forms using Laravel.

```
{!! Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::selectMonth('month', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::selectYear('year', Carbon\Carbon::now()->year, (new Carbon\Carbon('80 years ago'))->year, null , ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

This gives me :

[image: aa]

Which is good , except most people would leave them as is when registering.

I want them to display "year" , "day" , "Month" as default , so that the user has to select from the list.

Any ideas how to implement this.

Comment: This question is very similar and will likely help, seems this isn't possible but you can produce additional macro's to work around it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836731/laravel-4-formselectmonth-prepend-month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where that you now have twice `null` and last the current Carbon Datetime Year, these are the places in the methods that will show the `default` option.

But... The values you want, needs to be also in the datasource it's showing.
With these helpers you're using, that's not the case.
[This article](http://laravel.io/forum/06-03-2014-missing-0-index-for-selectmonth-and-selectyear-form-helpers) from laravel itself shows more information about this, and how to fix it.